# Magento 2 product price different on catalog page and on product page

Tags: magento2, price, eav, product-prices

I made a script for updating the price for a product using simple SQL queries, and I - expectedly - missed something, and now I have different price on catalog page and on the actual product page for a product. Price is the same on product page as on the admin product page, but on frontend catalog page, in the listing, for this product, price is different then on the product page and in admin. What tables need to be changed to synchronize these?

Answer (score 4):

**"value"** column in catalog_product_entity_decimal for the Product Page
 and **"price"** column for the catalog_product_index_price for catalog page. Hope it helps

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic please do mark it as correct answer if you got what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Check indexer info then reset if status is processing then do reindex for affected Title